# Use tomcat to bind to LDAP for more than authentication?

Tags: java, tomcat, ldap

I have a tomcat server that uses the JNDI Directory Realm to bind to an LDAP server to do authentication and this works fine.

However, I'd like to pull more information from the LDAP server (e.g., name, phone number, email, etc) and wondering what is the best way to do this?  So, I see there are two possibilites:

1) Is there a way to piggy-back on this already configured Realm?  If so, how?

2) Or do I have to make a separate LDAP connection?  If so, can I just the LDAP libraries and routines already in tomcat?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to bind to an LDAP server for retrieving information, go with plain [JNDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/), it's the standard API for accessing directories and performing CRUD operations over them, it'll just work even outside of Tomcat.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info, I just wanted to make sure I didn't do more work than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt any container will allow you access to the LDAP connection. There are provisions in some containers to retrieve entries within LDAP itself using LDAP search queries (say to retrieve groups), but containers are usually not designed to share the connection with a developer.

You can use JNDI like Oscar suggests or a host of [other APIs](http://directory.apache.org/api/java-api.html). Use a connection yourself since the spec says nothing about sharing connections with you.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info, I just wanted to make sure I didn't do more work than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

JNDI should not be used for new code. JNDI has very little to recommend it:

- JNDI has quite a number of software defects
- JNDI does not support the full range of the LDAP standards (and makes certain standard LDAP features impossible to use)
- the available examples are horrible
- it uses a disconnected parameter setting mechanism
- and it uses a deprecated configuration.

The [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) supports sensible constructs for connection and LDAP operations.

#### see also

- [LDAP: programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)
- [LDAP: search](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)

Comment: With respect, I find this a considerable overstatement. I use JNDI for some quite hairy LDAP operations, and, with the addition of some extra controls, I've only run into a small number of corner cases that it doesn't handle well, such as multi-attribute RDNs, and I've yet to find any actual bugs at all, in several years. I'm not the greatest fan of its API or programming model either. But it's usable for 95% of cases as far as i can see. I'm not aware what you mean by 'certain standard LDAP features impossible to use' or 'deprecated configuration' either.would you care to spell those out?

Comment: If you've had success with JNDI, then by all means continue to use it.

Comment: I'm just commenting because I've read your spiel quite a number of times now. I'd like to know more about it. Do you have some chapter and verse on the 'standard LDAP features impossible to use', 'deprecated configuration', 'software defects' etc?

Comment: A fair point. The subject of JNDI deserves a page on its own at [ldapguru.info](http://www.ldapguru.info). I'll put it together.